# osip2 compiling codeblocks errors

Tags: c++, sip

I'm trying to run a simple program with osip2 library version 5.0.0.
This is my code, and i'm having some errors that i cant figure out.
I'm using codeblocks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <osip2/osip.h>
#include <osipparser2/osip_parser.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

int main() {

  int i;    osip_t *osip;   i=osip_init(&osip);     if (i!=0)     return -1; }
```

Errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in cos2 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|211|error: field 'timer_a_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|213|error: field 'timer_b_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|215|error: field 'timer_d_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|232|error: field 'timer_e_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|234|error: field 'timer_f_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|236|error: field 'timer_k_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|254|error: field 'timer_g_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|256|error: field 'timer_h_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|258|error: field 'timer_i_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|273|error: field 'timer_j_start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|294|error: field 'srv_is_broken' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
..\libosip2-5.0.0\libosip2-5.0.0\include\osip2\osip.h|536|error: field 'start' has incomplete type 'timeval'|
C:\Users\emergency\Documents\analizer\cos2\main.cpp|8|error: '::main' must return 'int'|
C:\Users\emergency\Documents\analizer\cos2\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\emergency\Documents\analizer\cos2\main.cpp|16|error: cannot convert 'osip_message_t** {aka osip_message**}' to 'osip_t** {aka osip**}' for argument '1' to 'int osip_init(osip_t**)'|
||=== Build failed: 14 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

the errors showing this part of code in library:

```
  struct osip_ict {
    int timer_a_length;                           /**< Timer A A=T1, A=2xT1... (unreliable only) */
    struct timeval timer_a_start;                 /**< Timer A (retransmission) */
    int timer_b_length;                           /**< Timer B B = 64* T1 */
    struct timeval timer_b_start;                 /**< Timer B (fire when transaction timeout) */
    int timer_d_length;                           /**< Timer D D >= 32s for unreliable tr (or 0) */
    struct timeval timer_d_start;                 /**< Timer D */
    char *destination;                            /**< IP used to send requests */
    int port;                                     /**< port of next hop */
  };
```

Comment: i think timeval structure is is associated with Time.h file https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure `timeval` is not a standard C structure, it originated in the Unix world and is standardized in POSIX.

On Windows it's defined in the `<winsock2.h>` header file (because it's used by the `select` "network" function, see [this `struct timeval` reference on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information).

Since you include `<winsock2.h>` *after* the structure is used in `<osip2\osip.h>`, you get the error. The simplest solution is to rearrange the order of your include files.